# How to use $wpdb->prepare for dynamic value

Tags: php, wordpress, prepared-statement, wordpress-database

I build a sql with dynamic value from a array. How can I use placeholder or that dymanic condition.

I'm calling that function like this: `get_all_results("TABLE_NAME", ["column" => "VALUE"])`

```
    public static function get_all_results(string $table_name, array $where = []): array
    {
        global $wpdb;

        /**
         * Prepare condition
         * 
         * @var string
         */
        $condition = "";
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
            if ($index > 0) {
                $condition .= "AND ";
            }

            $condition .= "`$key` = '$value' ";
            $index += 1;
        }

        if (!empty($condition)) {
            $condition = " WHERE $condition ";
        }

        $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM %i {$condition} ", $table_name));
        return $results;
    }
```

How can I use $wpdb->prepare with my function or what should I do in this case ?

This line is the main problem for me, "Plugin Check" - plugin giving me error for this.

```
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM %i {$condition} ", $table_name));
```

```
WordPress.DB.PreparedSQL.InterpolatedNotPrepared Line 238 of file includes/classes/DB.php.
Use placeholders and $wpdb->prepare(); found interpolated variable $condition at "SELECT * FROM %i WHERE $condition".

"SELECT * FROM %i WHERE $condition",
```

Comment: Use `wpdb::quote_identifier` for your column names, and `wpdb::_real_escape` for the values.

Comment: @CBroe I will definitely use it thank you. But that's not the main problem though. I have edited my description, can you read it again please

Comment: Don't make us _guess_ what errors you could probably have gotten there.

Comment: @CBroe sorry for the issue, I have added that error.

Comment: That check apparently wants you to not put `$condition` directly into your query, but use a placeholder instead, and then pass `$condition` as an additional parameter. Only, I doubt it will actually work that way - the placeholders are for specific individual query parts, but you want to feed in something that is _already_ a mixture of query syntax, and data. So you'll likely end up with double encoding here, I would expect.

Comment: you're directly inserting the $condition string into the query, which could be a security risk if not handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I will use placeholders for each value in the `$where` array, in the below code that includes dynamically constructing the SQL query with placeholders for each condition, instead of directly inserting the condition string into the query. The actual values of these placeholders are then safely passed through `$wpdb->prepare()`, which effectively prevents SQL injection vulnerabilities, hope this helps

```
public static function get_all_results(string $table_name, array $where = []): array
{
    global $wpdb;

    //Prepare a condition
    $condition = "";
    $values = [];
    foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($condition)) {
            $condition .= " AND ";
        }

        $condition .= $wpdb->prepare("`$key` = %s", $value);
    }

    if (!empty($condition)) {
        $condition = " WHERE $condition ";
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `$table_name` $condition";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    return $results;
}
```